# Parsing text line by line across columns in Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

Using VBA or Interop.Word I would like to simply parse the text in a Word document line by line, regardless of whether the text in that line spans multiple columns.  As per the example below, I want:

Line 1 = "Line 1 Line 5"

Line 2 = "Line 2 Line 6"

Line 3 = "Line 3 Line 7"

etc.

I can't find any method, property or object in the Word Object Model that can facilitate this.  I tried exporting to PDF and then opening that same file again in Word, but the conversion does not retain the original text line by line and gets very scrambled in places.

[image: Word snapshot]

Comment: I'm skeptical that this is going to be possible. Word is simply not designed to internally "see" the page the way it lays out. The only thing I can think of that might have a chance is to work through every paragraph and check the Range.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage). If it returns the same value (more or less) for the same page, then it's in the same "line".

Comment: Thanks Cindy. Not sure I want to touch this anymore LOL! Just spent 30+ hours on it, but got it going. The problem was the doc came from a PDF generated by some stupid scanning software that interpreted a gap down the center of each page as a column. After some digging I found a way to export to Word with Acrobat Pro with the "layout" mode turned on - by default it's "flow". That then creates Rectangle objects (text boxes) around every block. I painfully found a way to parse most of it from that.

Comment: OK :-) Didn't want to leave you sitting without an answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment above: a workaround is to try to get the document recreated using layout mode. In this case the Word file came from an export of an Adobe PDF scan of a printed document, so it's only applicable in these situations.